# Jetty + Hibernate + JPA Transactions not persisting with H2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following method that does not persist the record.  If I run another query from a servlet and look this record up after it's updated by the rest service, I do not see the changes.  Any ideas why it's not being persisted?  I've also tried with `flush()` and/or `clear()` with no luck:

```
@POST
@Path("translations")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Translation updateTranslationValue(Translation translation,     
@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("reload_xlate", true);
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    TypedQuery<Translation> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT t FROM Translation t WHERE t.key = :key", Translation.class);
    query.setParameter("key", translation.getKey());
    Translation mappedTranslation = query.getSingleResult();
    mappedTranslation.setValue(translation.getValue());
    L.info("Updated: {}", mappedTranslation);
    //em.flush();
    //em.clear();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return mappedTranslation;
}
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyJPAJAXRS" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myds</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/seed.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Jetty data source is:

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
                <Arg>
                    <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
                        <!--<Set name="minimumPoolSize">5</Set>-->
                        <!--<Set name="maximumPoolSize">20</Set>-->
                        <Set name="dataSourceClassName">
                            org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
                        </Set>
                        <Call name="addDataSourceProperty">
                            <Arg>url</Arg>
                            <Arg>jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem</Arg>
                        </Call>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out for H2 the database pool settings need to be changed to 1 connection only:

```
<Set name="minimumPoolSize">1</Set>
<Set name="maximumPoolSize">1</Set>
```

That did the trick.